# Animation background image in WP8

Tags: image, animation, windows-phone-8

I have a pattern and set it as a background. I want to make it go up forever (like scene in run endless game)
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

No tiling effect built into Windows Phone 8 by default.  You have to just use `None`, `Fill`, `Uniform`, and `UniformToFill` if you don't want to build your own or use someone else library/code.

You can easily achieve a Tiling effect by using a `Canvas` and some rudimentary algebra and graphical calls.  But best to learn from example, I guess:

[WindowsPhone TilePanel: Repeating(Tiling) image background(C#-XAML)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/windowsphone-tilepanel-d5b75094)